# props not updating in child component after parent component's state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, client-server

I am working on a ToDo application and I passed an array of tasks with objects inside it but after passing tasks as props it never updates in ***ToDoList.***
Please help me I appreciate your help and would like to know the logic behind it.

**App.js** :-
This is entry file where all the code is present

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddToDo from './components/addToDo';
import Filter from './components/Filter';
import ToDoList from './components/toDoList';

window.id = 0;

function App() {
    const [value, setvalue] = useState('');
    const [tasks, settasks] = useState([]);
    const handleChange = (e) => setvalue(e.target.value);
    const handleTasks = (val) => {
        tasks.push({ text: val, completed: false, id: window.id++ });
        settasks(tasks);
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
    };

    return (
        <div className="row flex-center flex-middle flex">
            <div className="border border-primary padding-large margin-large no-responsive paper">
                <h3>Narries ToDo</h3>
                <AddToDo onChange={handleChange} value={value} onAdd={handleTasks} />
                <ToDoList tasks={tasks} />
                <Filter />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**AddToDo**
Here is where we added the task by changing state in app.js

```js
import React from 'react';

const AddToDO = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col padding-right-small">
                <input type="text" placeholder="New Todo" value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="col padding-left-small">
                <button value="Add" className="paper-btn btn-small" onClick={() => props.onAdd(props.value)}>
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AddToDO;
```

**ToDoList.js**:- This is where it should update tasks props.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ToDoList = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="child-borders">
            {props.tasks.map((task, id) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        className={
                            'padding-small margin-small ' +
                            (task.completed ? 'background-primary' : 'shadow shadow-hover')
                        }
                        key={id}
                    >
                        {task.text}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ToDoList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mutated the original tasks array. Every time you change the value, tasks array has overwritten. So you need to update the tasks array as:

```
const handleTasks = (val) => {
  let customTask = { text: val, completed: false, id: window.id++ };
  settasks(tasks => [...tasks, customTask]);
  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> you should never directly mutate/change your state remove this line `tasks.push({ text: val, completed: false, id: window.id++ });`
> in your ToDoList.js it should only be task and not task.text

Comment: Thanks, Pratik, this problem is now solved.